# How can I fix the issue that when working on battery, my laptop turns off without any notification?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, power, battery-life

I have a Sony VPCEH 2010 Laptop and Win 10 is installed. When on battery, If the battery arrives at about 30%, my laptop suddenly turns off without any "Battery Low" warning and after plugging and turning on, it shows that the battery has become completely empty.
A professional checked the laptop and said that there is no issue with the battery and seems like the windows has been damaged.
Also reinstalling the windows did not helped.

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?
Thanks

Comment: That's a classic sign of a failing battery. I'd find another 'professional', or just another battery.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

(1) Update BIOS and the Power Driver (both).

(2) Restart and now reset the Battery.

Charge to Full Charge.  Unplug and allow to fully run down until shutdown (this will not hurt it doing it once). Plug in, allow to charge to Full Charge.

Restart and check Battery operation.

If the computer still shuts down at 30% , you likely need to replace the battery.